# constructing arithmetic progressions from loop

Tags: python

I am trying to work out a program that would calculate the diagonal coefficients of pascal's triangle.

[image]

For those who are not familiar with it, the general terms of sequences are written below.

1st row = 1 1 1 1 1....

2nd row = N0(natural number) // 1 = 1 2 3 4 5 ....

3rd row = N0(N0+1) // 2 = 1 3 6 10 15 ...

4th row = N0(N0+1)(N0+2) // 6 = 1 4 10 20 35 ...

the subsequent sequences for each row follows a specific pattern and it is my goal to output those sequences in a for loop with number of units as input.

```
def figurate_numbers(units):
    row_1 = str(1) * units
    row_1_list = list(row_1)

    for i in range(1, units):
    sequences are 
                  row_2 = n // i 
                  row_3 = (n(n+1)) // (i(i+1))
                  row_4 = (n(n+1)(n+2)) // (i(i+1)(i+2))

>>> def figurate_numbers(4): # coefficients for 4 rows and 4 columns
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 10]
[1, 4, 10, 20]   # desired output
```

How can I iterate for both `n` and `i` in one loop such that each sequence of corresponding row would output coefficients?

Comment: What does the variable units and N suppose to equal?

Comment: @Zx4161 N is counting natural numbers starting from 1 2 3 4 5 and so on. units is the number of rows and columns.

Comment: copy Pascal triangle definition from a text book or wikipedia

Comment: @Serge But I am not trying to output coefficient of the pascal's triangle. My goal is to output the diagonal coefficients.

Comment: I mean copy some definition from an authoritative source of whatever you compute, we do not have to decipher your interpretation

Comment: from wikipedia looks akin to fibbonachi sequence computing. just do it on rows/arrays. Note generally recursive fibbonachi in Python is very inefficient unless one uses lru cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map or a list comprehension to hide a loop.

```
def f(x, i): 
    return lambda x: ...

row = [ [1] * k ]

for i in range(k):
   row[i + 1] = map( f(i), row[i])
```

where f is function that descpribe the dependency on previous element of row.

Other possibility adapt a recursive Fibbonachi to rows. Numpy library allows for array arifmetics so even do not need map. Also python has predefined libraries for number of combinations etc, perhaps can be used.

To compute efficiently, without nested loops, use Rational Number based solution from

https://medium.com/@duhroach/fast-fun-with-pascals-triangle-6030e15dced0 .

```
from fractions import Fraction

def pascalIndexInRowFast(row,index):
    lastVal=1
    halfRow = (row>>1)

    #early out, is index < half? if so, compute to that instead
    if index > halfRow:     
        index = halfRow - (halfRow - index)

    for i in range(0, index):
        lastVal = lastVal * (row - i) / (i + 1)

return lastVal

def pascDiagFast(row,length):

    #compute the fractions of this diag
    fracs=[1]*(length)
    for i in range(length-1):
        num = i+1
        denom = row+1+i
        fracs[i] = Fraction(num,denom)

    #now let's compute the values
    vals=[0]*length

    #first figure out the leftmost tail of this diag
    lowRow = row + (length-1)
    lowRowCol = row
    tail = pascalIndexInRowFast(lowRow,lowRowCol)

    vals[-1] = tail

    #walk backwards!
    for i in reversed(range(length-1)):
        vals[i] = int(fracs[i]*vals[i+1])

return vals
```

Comment: So I have to pre-define the general term of the sequence, then apply the sequence onto each row?

Comment: It is one possible solution. Other would be extend some fibbonachi number program on rows

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the triangle:

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import pascal
>>> pascal(4)
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  3,  6, 10],
       [ 1,  4, 10, 20]], dtype=uint64)
>>> pascal(4).tolist()
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 6, 10], [1, 4, 10, 20]]
```